# chef-solo unable to find Chef::Resource::PythonPip

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra

I'm setting up a python virtualenv setup via chef.  Chef-solo is complaining of a missing method in `Chef::Resource::PythonPip` I believe:

```
$ chef-solo -c (my path)/solo.rb -l debug -j (my path)/solo.json
...
[Thu, 08 Dec 2011 16:49:58 +0000] DEBUG: Loading Recipe python::pip via include_recipe
[Thu, 08 Dec 2011 16:49:58 +0000] DEBUG: Found recipe pip in cookbook python
[Thu, 08 Dec 2011 16:49:58 +0000] DEBUG: Loading Recipe python::virtualenv via include_recipe
[Thu, 08 Dec 2011 16:49:58 +0000] DEBUG: Found recipe virtualenv in cookbook python
[Thu, 08 Dec 2011 16:49:58 +0000] DEBUG: I am not loading python::pip, because I have already seen it.
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/recipe.rb:200:in `method_missing': Cannot find Chef::Resource::PythonPip for python_pip (NameError)
```

I setup this server with:

```
sudo apt-get -q -y update
sudo apt-get -q -y install rubygems unzip ruby1.8-dev chef
sudo gem install chef net-ssh-multi
```

Is there a gem or another package I'll need to get this running on Ubuntu 10.04?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 4):

Try putting:

```
depends python
```

in your metadata.rb file.